# Using GAN for generating data to augment training data

Tags: regression, classification, tensorflow, keras, gan

I want to model an experiment data using a neural network but as the data set size is too small (25 samples), I decided to use a GAN to generate more data. The input is a 4×1 tensor representing 4 input floating point value, and output is a single float number.

But the problem is that I can't create a suitable discriminator model to distinguish real experimental data.
I added and subtracted a little to/from real data to create some fake training data.

The models that Keras Tuner finds can't distinguish real data.

Can anyone suggest some advice about how to create a discriminator model?

Can a multi layer perceptron classifier distinguish points belonging to output of a function from other irrelevant points?

Any other data augmentation methods for regression is welcome.

Comment: I wouldn't use a GAN here as you have too few data points. Without more information about the context, I don't think it would be appropriate to tell you how to augment your data

Comment: My data belong to a simple function, something like a 2nd order polynomial. All are normalized between 0 and 1. I think there is no need to have more than one or two hidden layers. I found a generator model that have both loss and validation loss as low as 2e-4 and in same magnitude so I'm sure that it doesn't over fit. But output of any model I find with keras Tuner, say 1 or 0 for any data point regardless of real or fake.